# Run postbuild action for every test on specific jenkins node

Tags: jenkins

I have a remote agent and multiple local agents on my jenkins server. I have a script that I want to run only after those test that are builded on the remote agent. Is it possible somehow?
Thanks

Comment: You should probably take a step back: what's the logical difference between the remote agent and the local agents? Why does this script need to run only on the remote agent? Is it possible to re-write the script to be a NOP if run on a local agent?

Comment: Alternatively: is the remote agent run a different job, or could it be refactored to be? You could certainly configure those differently.

Answer (score -1):

Using jenkins pipeline you have the possiblity of running actions according to the result of the build. Take a look here:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post

You can even separate your build in "stages" and run actions according to the result of the stage using the same method.

On the entire pipeline, or on a specific stage, or even on your post actions, you can choose which node does the job.

Considering you run a stage on a specific node you could:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage ('Build') {
            agent { label "SLAVE1" }
            steps {
                // Stuff to do
            }
            post {
                 always {
                     // stuff
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or at end end of your pipeline in a post block:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage ("Build") {
            agent { label "SLAVE" }
            steps {
                // stuff
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        // Or failure, unstable, success...
        always {
            node('SLAVE1'){
                // stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an answer to the question, which is "How can I run a postbuild action if the build was run on a specific agent." While the `post` block is certainly very configurable, it does not have a `post { agent { label '...' } { doThing() } }` option.

Comment: You can run a post block on a specific stage in that way: 
`stage("XXX"){ agent { node { label "YYY" } } setps { //stuff } post { // stuff} }`. 
As you can also run the post block on a specific node in that way: 
`post { always { node('YYY'){ // stuff } }`
I use both quite often in my pipelines.